# How to install jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am a novice in jQuery plugin's usage.   Now I am faced with adding a new plugin to my project.

It is the jQuery Validation plugin.

I downloaded the archive from [the official site](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Content of this archive looks like this:

[image]

As I understand, there are a lot of redundant files which I shouldn't install in my project (`demo` for example).

Can you briefly describe archive structure and which files I should use?

**EDIT**:

lib content:
[image]

Comment: Did you look inside the folders yet?  Open `dist` and the plugin itself is called `jquery.validate.js` or `jquery.validate.min.js`.  You can use either one.  The `additional-methods` file is optional.   Also see [official website](http://jqueryvalidation.org) and [SO Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is enough to look in the dist folder. Probably it would be enough to have the `jquery-validate.js` file, or the `min` version of it if you don't want to browse the code. (+ probably things in the lib folder)

However usually we keep the folder of the plugin in a Scripts folder with at least the dist and lib subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I used it once and I only needed the "jquery.validate.js"-File
You can download it from the links on this page
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Example: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js

All the other files you downloaded are I guess for the demo (If you already have jQuery, otherwise you will need jQuery as well).

Answer (score 0):

The code to include in your own work is file is described in the [readme](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/README.md) and [bower.json](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/bower.json) lists the minimum **jquery.js** version which is needed - the jquery.js files are in the `lib` (library) and are used for all jquery plug-ins. `Bower.json` states no other scripts are required. You can create a `js` for the `.js` files.

The `src\localization` folder contains messages in non-English languages which you might need if the validation error messages need if languages other than English are on your website (optional).

As you work through coding with the plug-in and viewing/using the demos it will become obvious which additional files you need from `src` (part of this release) or from `lib` (not part of the validation plug-in). The minimum is 2 files: `jquery.js` and the actual plug-in. The extra files are just for `github` organization, demos, instructions or optional features. From the `readme` instructions with directory names, you can add this to your HTML where you want the validated form to appear in the `<body>`:

```
<form>
<input required>
</form>
<script src="js\jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js\jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
$("form").validate();
</script>
```